# Configuring keys on Huion 420 - Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: bash, scripts, wayland, tablet

I used the bash script on MX linux to program the Huion 420 keys:

```
xsetwacom --set "HUION H420 Pad pad" Button 1 "key +ctrl +z -z -ctrl"
xsetwacom --set "HUION H420 Pad pad" Button 2 "key +ctrl +  -ctrl"
xsetwacom --set "HUION H420 Pad pad" Button 3 "key +ctrl -  -ctrl"
```

and made it autorun on start.

But now, I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 and when tried to do the same thing, it says Wayland isn't compatible with xsetwacom (https://github.com/linuxwacom/xf86-input-wacom/wiki/Wayland).

Any ideas what to do?

Tnx

Answer (score 2):

Older versions of Wayland had issues with Wacom tablets. Unless you have a touch screen/convertible computer, you really don't need Wayland.

You need to switch to X.Org to fix the issue.

Log out and switch to the non-wayland/X.Org session in the login screen.

[image]
 <sup>Image source: [OMG! Ubuntu!](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2021/01/ubuntu-21-04-will-use-wayland-by-default)</sup>

Comment: Well thank you so much! I didn't even know I could log in like that! Mine has ''Ubuntu'' and ''Ubuntu on Xorg'' so I I'll try.

Comment: It's not working...the whole script is `#!/bin/sh
xsetwacom --set "HUION H420 Pad pad" Button 1 "key +ctrl +z -z -ctrl"
xsetwacom --set "HUION H420 Pad pad" Button 2 "key +ctrl + -ctrl"
xsetwacom --set "HUION H420 Pad pad" Button 3 "key +ctrl - -ctrl" `

Comment: This answer fixes the wayland issue, but there might be other issues with the script. Can you edit the question and post the error in the output of the program?

Comment: there is no error output, the script doesn't work (when I open Krita or any drawing software, the keys don't do what I programmed them to do). That message about Wyland compatibility came when I tried to list the wacom devices via terminal (`xsetwacom --list devices`).

Comment: I don't know how to fix the Wacom issue. Perhaps you can open an issue at https://github.com/linuxwacom/xf86-input-wacom/issues

Comment: forget it. All this time the option was hidden in Settings, in GUI. There, under option ''Graphic tablet'', you can adjust everything. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @ToniMalcic Can you [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1481350/edit) my answer to include more details, and perhaps with some screenshots?